# Snowflake - convert string to datetime

Tags: datetime, time, timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-timestamp

I am using snowflake and I have date as a string in this format

> '2021-04-01 08:00:05.577209+00'

I want to convert it to DateTime. I used the below code to do this (I trim '+00' from each string first). However I think I defined it somehow wrong, so I keep getting errors.

```
TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ(left(ts,len(ts)-4),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'),
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to trim the `+00` off? just do it like this:

```sql
select to_timestamp_ntz('2021-04-01 08:00:05.577209+00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF+00')
```

Comment: Hi @simon, when I used your code I get below error _Can't parse '"2021-03-31 20:00:33.205903+00"' as timestamp with format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF+00'_

Comment: Can you show your exact code? because this works for me: `select to_timestamp_ntz('2021-03-31 20:00:33.205903+00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF+00');`

Comment: Just to add that the proposed solution from @SimonDarr works for me too.

Comment: I download data from Azure Data Lake and create external table. This is just a format of date in csv file  _2021-04-01 08:00:11.211201+00_. The code I use in snowflake for this column looks like this _TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ((value: c4::STRING),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF+00')_

Comment: please share the full SQL and error message returned

Answer (score 0):

1. It would be better to use left(ts,len( ts)-3) instead of left(ts,len( ts)-4) to trim last 3 characters.
2. Can you check your data and be sure it is '2021-04-01 08:00:05.577209+00' cause it works as expected (tested with both):

   select ts,
   left(ts,len( ts)-3) trimmed,
   TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ(left(ts,len( ts)-3),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') result
   from values ('2021-04-01 08:00:05.577209+00') tmp (ts);

Result:

```
+-------------------------------+----------------------------+-------------------------+
|              TS               |          TRIMMED           |         RESULT          |
+-------------------------------+----------------------------+-------------------------+
| 2021-04-01 08:00:05.577209+00 | 2021-04-01 08:00:05.577209 | 2021-04-01 08:00:05.577 |
+-------------------------------+----------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunatelly I am still getting error _Can't parse '"2021-03-31 17:00:20.975882' as timestamp with format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'_

Answer (score 0):

I have found answer on my question. I was reading data from CSV files on Azure Data Lake and I haven't noticed quotes in a columns. When I deleted them everything is working fine.

Comment: This is why I asked you to check your data :)